# Get duplicates for two columns with LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, linq-to-dataset

LINQ drives me crazy. Why does following query not return the duplicates, whereas it works with only one identifier? Where is my error?

```
' generate some test-data '
Dim source As New DataTable
source.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RowNumber", GetType(Int32)))
source.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Value1", GetType(Int32)))
source.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Value2", GetType(Int32)))
source.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Text", GetType(String)))
Dim rnd As New Random()
For i As Int32 = 1 To 100
    Dim newRow = source.NewRow
    Dim value = rnd.Next(1, 20)
    newRow("RowNumber") = i
    newRow("Value1") = value
    newRow("Value2") = (value + 1)
    newRow("Text") = String.Format("RowNumber{0}-Text", i)
    source.Rows.Add(newRow)
Next
' following query does not work, it always has Count=0 '
' although it works with only one identifier '
Dim dupIdentifiers = From row In source
         Group row By grp = New With {.Val1 = row("Value1"), .Val2 = row("Value2")}
         Into Group
         Where Group.Count > 1
         Select idGroup = New With {grp.Val1, grp.Val2, Group.Count}
```

---

**Edit**: Following is the complete solution, thanks to [@Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530906/get-duplicates-for-two-columns-with-linq/7530944#7530944) :)

```
Dim dupKeys = From row In source
        Group row By grp = New With {Key .Val1 = CInt(row("Value1")), Key .Val2 = CInt(row("Value2"))}
        Into Group Where Group.Count > 1
        Select RowNumber = CInt(Group.FirstOrDefault.Item("RowNumber"))

Dim dupRows = From row In source
        Join dupKey In dupKeys 
        On row("RowNumber") Equals dupKey 
        Select row

If dupRows.Any Then
    ' create a new DataTable from the first duplicate rows '
    Dim dest = dupRows.CopyToDataTable
End If
```

The main problem with grouping was that i must make them `key` properties.
The next problem in my above code was to get the duplicate rows from the original table.
Because nearly every row has a duplicate(according to two fields), the result DataTable contained 99 of 100 rows and not only the 19 duplicate values.  I needed to select only the first duplicate row and join them with the original table on the PK.

```
Select RowNumber = CInt(Group.FirstOrDefault.Item("RowNumber"))
```

Although this works in my case, maybe someone can explain me how to select only the duplicates from the original table if i would have had only composite keys.

---

**Edit**: I'v answered the last part of the question myself, so here is all i need:

```
Dim dups = From row In source
         Group By grp = New With {Key .Value1 = CInt(row("Value1")), Key .Value2 = CInt(row("Value2"))}
         Into Group Where Group.Count > 1
         Let Text = Group.First.Item("Text")
         Select Group.First

If dups.Any Then
      Dim dest = dups.CopyToDataTable
End If
```

I needed the [Let-Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641931/is-linqs-let-keyword-better-than-its-into-keyword/641944#641944) in order to keep the other column(s) into the same context and return only the first row of the grouped dups. On this way i can use `CopyToDataTable` to create a DataTable from the duplicate rows.

Only a few lines of code overall (i can save the second query to find the rows in the original table) to find duplicates on multiple columns and create a DataTable of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the way [anonymous types work in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) - they're mutable by default; only `Key` properties are included for hashing and equality. Try this:

```
Group row By grp = New With {Key .Val1 = row("Value1"), Key .Val2 = row("Value2")}
```

(In C# this wouldn't be a problem - anonymous types in C# are always immutable in all properties.)

Comment: Thank you. I've edited your question because it was too late in the Select, i need it in the first place where i group the rows. I hope i will remember this fact.

Comment: Yes, the duplicates are correct. But now i'm stuck on the next lines where i want to join the original table with the duplicates. The result(`dupRows`) is the full table(100 rows) and not only the dups(19 rows).

Comment: The reason for this was that the `Group By` selects only the duplicate rows once. But because i joined them with the original table, i selected also the other duplicate rows. The result was that nearly all rows were in the result table. I needed to select an identifier in the `grouped` rows. Although this works here i'd like to know what i could do if i would have had no `PK` but only composite keys(see my edited question).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you can use the "Key" of an `IGrouping` to get the whole key - is that what you're after?

Comment: My (theoretical) problem is how to identify rows in a DataTable when i have no identifier but composite keys with duplicate values. The above works because i can select the first duplicate's `RowNumber` value and later select all rows with these identifiers to create a new DataTable from the duplicates. But it would not work when i would `Join On` the two columns, because i would get also the other duplicate rows and not only one. Maybe it's better to create another question from this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I suspect so, yes... and it would probably be better for me to go to bed now, too :) I'll have more chance of grokking the question in the morning...

Comment: It was the Let-Keyword that i was missing(see my last edit). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

*What I use to get duplicate rows across two columns in a EF table to show up as duplicates using Lin-q with C Sharp:*

```
            var DuplicatesFoundInTable =
            entities.LocationDatas
           .Where(c => c.TrailerNumber != null && c.CarrierName != null && (c.TrailerNumber ?? string.Empty) != string.Empty && (c.CarrierName ?? string.Empty) != string.Empty)
           .GroupBy(o => new { o.TrailerNumber, o.CarrierName }, l => new { customer.TrailerNumber, customer.CarrierName })
           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
           .Select(y => y.Key)
           .ToList();
```

*When I want to see if it is a duplicate on inputs (if the entry already exists in two columns):*

```
          //Check to see if any rows are the same values on TrailerNumber and CarrierName for inputs. 
            bool AlreadyInTableComparer = entities.LocationDatas.Any(l => String.Compare(l.TrailerNumber, customer.TrailerNumber, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0 && String.Compare(l.CarrierName, customer.CarrierName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0);
            bool AlreadyInTable = entities.LocationDatas.Any(t => t.TrailerNumber == customer.TrailerNumber && t.CarrierName == customer.CarrierName);
```

*SQL Server Checking for duplicates (commented out delete duplicates):*

```
 WITH CTE
 AS
  (
 SELECT [TrailerNumber], [CarrierName]
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY TrailerNumber Order by TrailerNumber, 
    CarrierName) AS NumRows, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY TrailerNumber, 
   CarrierName Order by CarrierName) AS NumRows2
   FROM [dbo].[LocationData] --Please note, duplicates are shown in this 
   table.
   WHERE  TrailerNumber != '' AND CarrierName != '' 
   )
   SELECT [TrailerNumber], [CarrierName], [NumRows2] FROM CTE WHERE NumRows2 > 1
   --DELETE FROM CTE WHERE NumRows2 > 1  --Delete Duplicates.
```

*Validate SQL Server to prove correct against CTE filtering:*

```
    SELECT TrailerNumber, CarrierName, COUNT(*) AS Duplicates
    FROM [dbo].[LocationData]
    WHERE TrailerNumber IS NOT NULL OR CarrierName IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY TrailerNumber, CarrierName
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1 AND TrailerNumber != '' AND CarrierName != ''
```